# What do I use for HOST to connect to a remote server with mysqldb python?

Tags: python, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-python, host

Things to note in advance:

- I am using wampserver 2.2
- Ive forwarded port 80
- I added a rule to my firewall to accept traffic through port 3306
- I have added "Allow from all" in directory of "A file i forget"
- My friend can access my phpmyadmin server through his browser
- I am quite the novice, so bear with me.

I am trying to get my friend to be able to alter my databases on my phpmyadmin server through 
python. I am able to do so on the host machine using "127.0.0.1" as the HOST. My Question is, does he have to use my external ip as the HOST or my external ip/phpmyadmin/ as the HOST? And if using the external ip iscorrect...What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

If your phpmyadmin runs on the same machine as mysql-server, 127.0.0.1 is enough (and safer if your mysql server binds to 127.0.0.1, rather than 0.0.0.0) if you use tcp(rather than unix socket).